# Php login page code issue. Login page load message display invalid login

Tags: php, mysql

Every time at login page load message display invaild login. It is not checking the if condition directly goes to else. I echo my sql query and it is perfectly working fine. But I am not understand where I am making mistake. can you please help me.

my code below,

```
<?php
    #$error = "";
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "lg_db";
        $tb_name = "lgin";

        mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password")or die("Cannot connect");
        mysql_select_db("$dbname")or die("Cannot connect to Database");

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
$username=stripslashes($username);
$pass=stripslashes($pass);
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$pass=mysql_real_escape_string($pass);

        $sql="SELECT * FROM $tb_name WHERE Name='$username' and Password='$pass'";

        $result=mysql_query($sql);

        $count1=mysql_num_rows($result);

        if($count1 >=1)
        {
            session_start();
           $_SESSION['simple_login'] = $username;
            header("Location: index_new.php");
            exit();

        }else{
                 $error="Invalid Login";
        }
?>
```

Comment: Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and check for errors in your SQL as well [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) (so *at the very least* do `$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`)

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Sorry, did by mistake. Wrong dupe target.

Comment: `if($count1 >=1)` use => `if($count1 >0)` you're checking if it is higher than 1 OR equal to 1. That will fail if you only have the one record.

Comment: Btw, I wouldn't use that code at all. It's old, unsafe and storing plain text passwords. Do not put this live.

Comment: Please use PDO mysql_* methods are deprecated...

Comment: @Fred-ii- Uuuh, that `>=` is `greater than OR equal to`, so if it's 1 or higher. Not 1 *and* higher.

Comment: @Qirel edited: I stand corrected ;-) thanks.

Comment: ok, I'm outta here.

Comment: @Fred-ii : I made the change in code. if($count1 >0) also tried if($count==1) still same result.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Still won't fail if there's 1 record :p It'll fail if there are zero records, so I'm guessing there are some unreported errors here causing the query to fail or return 0 rows.

Comment: @RockLinux See my first comment, implement that and report back what (if any) errors you get.

Comment: your form may be failing or your query is failing silently if the column length is too short. There could be many reasons as to why that is.

Comment: @Qirel this one's all yours. I can't keep commenting here.

Comment: @Qirel : I tried the error checking but output is 0 only. If I comment else part and put my username and password it works. but if I put the else part again it failed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : table column length is varchar 50 for both.

Comment: Try echo the value of `$count1` and see what it has

Comment: Guys, Thank you for your support and help! My problem got resolved.  I have added if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") and before that POST data from html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your support and help! My problem got resolved. I have added `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")` and before that POST data from html file.